# SMTP proxy to investigate outgoing e-mails not being sent?

Tags: windows, email, proxy, smtp

For some reason, using the same e-mail account that works the rest of the time, some outgoing e-mails aren't being sent by my ISP's SMTP server:

> Error reading from network Cause: Eudora got tired of waiting for the server. (10100)

I suspect my ISP uses a blacklist and refuses to send e-mails to some recipients; I don't see any other possible explanation.

To investigate, I'd like to install a local proxy on my Windows host between my e-mail client (Eudora) and my ISP's SMTP server to see what's going on.

Do you know of a program that could do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You're probably right that something's blacklisted, but you may be headed the wrong direction here.  I'd head over to mxtoolbox.com and read and learn about RBL's.  You can also test IP's and hostnames on the site to find out what's blacklisted.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turns out my ISP's SMTP server wrongly thought the email contained SPAM but the email client didn't return that error message.